# What types the word other in sets methods refer to?

Tags: python-3.x, set

In the help of the `Built-in` type `set` I found the word `other`

> intersection(other, ...)
>   set & other & ...
>
> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

My question is what are the limits of other's type, is it any iterable or any convertible to `set` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup)  (line 1236+) [`PyAnySet_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/set.html#c.PyAnySet_Check) is called, which checks whether `other` is a `set`, `frozenset` or subtype.

If this check fails, [`PyObject_GetIter`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetIter) is called with `other` as the argument in order to get an iterator.

So any iterable or object with an *is-a* relationship with `set` or `frozenset` will do.

Comment: The source link  you provide is very constructive. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Read the rest of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.intersection):

> Note, the non-operator versions of `union()`, `intersection()`, `difference()`, and `symmetric_difference()`, `issubset()`, and `issuperset()` methods **will accept any iterable as an argument**. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: +1 for showing the most obvious way to learn this thing, the documentation, and for pointing out the mistake in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For some methods, like `intersection()`, `other` can be any iterable, while for some operator based counterparts of some methods like `issubset()` (operator counterpart being `<=`), the `other` has to be a set too. You can test for yourself too. Some examples here:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> l = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> l
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> s.issubset(l)
False
>>> s <= l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    s <= l
TypeError: unorderable types: set() <= list()
>>> s <= set(l)
False
>>> s.intersection(l)
{1, 3, 5}
>>>
```

Comment: That’s the wrong version. In Python 3, `issubset` works with any iterable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't say `issubset` doesn't work, it simply returned False in my example, which means it worked already.

Comment: Your answer claims that “for some other methods like `issubset()`, the other has to be a set too.” That claim is wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oops, missed that, I wanted to write the operator counterpart. Will correct it now.